# Snowflake Connected Apps - Provider setup

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking for technical documentation around using Snowflake's connected apps feature. (https://www.snowflake.com/blog/powered-by-snowflake-how-connected-applications-work/)

Essentially I want the provider to connect to the customer's Snowflake account via provider Snowflake account, and all the computation that happens will be charged at the customer's end.

I found one piece of [documentation](https://medium.com/snowflake/implementing-a-connected-application-a1395d7ce70d) for setting up the customer's snowflake to make sure it's ready to share data. But I am not able to find the documentation for setting up the provider's account to establish a connection.

(I want to be able to achieve this via APIs as well)

Please let me know if my question is confusing.

Comment: Hi - in the article you’ve linked to it describes how to connect in the section “How Connected Apps Query Data”. What additional information are you looking for or what is the specific issue you are unsure about?